# Echo only last 10 values of array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-splice

i've this array build

```
 <?php
    $bidding_history = $current_bidding_data;
    if(is_array($bidding_history) && !empty($bidding_history) ){ 
    ?>

        <ul class="list-group">
        <?php
        foreach($bidding_history as $kk => $bhistory){
        ?>
```

with $bhistory being echoed as follows,

```
<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right"><small><?php echo $bhistory['username'] ?></small></span>
```

i want to echo only the last 10 lines of $bhistory.

i've tried to array_splice

```
<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right"><small><?php echo array_splice ($bidding_history['username'], -1, 10, true) ?></small></span>
```

but on the front end i'm getting an error code: 
Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

i do not know what am doing wrong, need help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_slice();` for this.

Here an example:

```
<?php
$bidding_history_new = array_slice($bidding_history, -10);
foreach($bidding_history_new as $kk => $bhistory){
    //whatever you do here

}
?>
```

More info about PHP's `array_slice();` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: You can simplify it with `array_slice($bidding_history, -10)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer maybe doesn't lie with `array_slice`.

You can look at the last 10 elements of an array quite easily with a for loop:

```
for($i = count($bidding_history) - 10; $i < count($bidding_history); $i++) {
?>
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right"><small>
<?php 
    echo $bidding_history[$i]['username'] 
?>
    </small></span>
<?php
}
```

Or

```
for($i = count($bidding_history) - 10; $i < count($bidding_history); $i++) {
    //...whatever you want to do...
    $username = $bidding_history[$i]['username'];
}
```